# logout of CLI & reenter GUI

Tags: command-line, gui, logout

My video drivers are currently still in beta, so every now and then, the desktop environment malfunctions especially when (dis)connecting a second monitor.

Thankfully, there is [a way to restart the gui without having to reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180628/how-can-i-logout-from-the-gui-using-cli).

However, `tty1` is still logged in.  If I try to logout of `tty1` I can't <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> back in to the gui.

How can I both restart the gui *and* logout of the tty that restarts the gui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo service lightdm restart && logout
```