# How to end X session?

Tags: window-manager, gdm, openbox, display-manager

Is there a generic way to orderly end X session regardless of display mangager or window manager?

More specifically, I use different windows managers for different users, and after reboot one user cannot login back, because gdm says I am already logged in. I assume this is because I leave dirty state (that user ends session with `openbox --exit`).

Comment: Try logging out differently - some methods listed [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/180628/how-can-i-logout-from-the-gui-using-cli). Also, you could kill all that user's running processes by executing `kill -9 -1` as that user - but **don't run it as root**.