# Launch Logoff Screen Using Terminal On Lubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, lubuntu, command-line, logout

How can I open the logoff screen from my terminal instead of clicking the logoff button? This is on Lubuntu 13.10.

Screenshot of the logoff screen:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command is:

```
lxsession-logout
```

Comment: it is not exactly the same, in the logout screen apears with a lubuntu logo, with command lxsession-logout apears without a logo. But it works anyway....

Comment: That did not work for me on 15.04 but the tip here did: http://askubuntu.com/questions/180628/how-can-i-logout-from-the-gui-using-cli