# Can't download anything when Installing Ubuntu with Minimal?

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-minimal

I'm Having this little Problem when trying to do an install from the Minimal CD, No matter which Mirror i pick, nothing downloads.

What's worse is that I tried to install the Minimal CD in a VM and everything downloaded accordingly but the VM wouldn't boot but that's another problem, now that I'm using it in a real System nothing downloads, What could be the problem?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The driver for your network adapter is not being loaded.

You need to go in to your live system find out which adapter you have an what driver is being loaded for it, you can do that looking at the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -i net -A2` in a terminal, for me I get the following:

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. Device [1462:7550]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

then in your minimal CD installation you need to go to another TTY and manually load the necessary driver module for your listed adapter.

I am sure you probably know this, but here are some questions for future reverence:

- [What is a tty, and how do I access a tty?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66195/what-is-a-tty-and-how-do-i-access-a-tty)

And here is more information on how to list and load driver modules using a TTY:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Loadable_Modules

Comment: Thanks I've forgot that the kernel in Oneiric didn't work with my Realltek chip,