# Unable to sign into 11.10 user

Tags: 12.04, unity, compiz, files

I upgraded to 12.04 today from 11.10 from a bootable thumbdrive. The upgrade took approximately 8 hours. I had to make a new user, and I'm unable to sign into my user that I used in 11.10. I can see my files in the /home/ directory, but there isn't an option to sign into that user on the boot screen. I am also unable to use the normal "Ubuntu" setting, I get a black screen with that. I have to use "Ubuntu 2D". Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You have a permissions problem.

What you need to do is get to a [terminal as explained here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66195/what-is-a-tty-and-how-do-i-access-a-tty), and sign in with your username and password.

Then, you need to run the following:

`sudo chmod -R 750 /home/$yourusername`

Then, type:

`sudo reboot` to restart your computer.

Once that's done, you should be able to log in via lightdm.

Comment: When I push Ctrl-Alt-F1, my monitor goes blank with a "Sync out of Range" error. Ctrl-Alt-F7 brings me back to the desktop. Does it have to be one of these weird terminals? Can't I just use the "Terminal" app?

Comment: When I tried that command in the normal terminal app, it corrupted all my files and I had to do a clean reinstall.

Comment: @Seth Yes, you have to do it in the 'weird terminal'. Otherwise, what you had happen happens.

Comment: Well, why did my monitor not work when I tried Ctrl-Alt-F1?

Comment: @Seth that is worth asking another question, since I don't know. :(

Comment: Well, thanks for the help. I'll ask another question. My monitor shows that "Sync out of Range" thing when starting up and shutting down, like when it shows "Ubuntu" and has orange dots moving below it in 11.10.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround could be :
move you old user folders and files to your new user home.

If you want to keep all your setting you must view the hidden folders from nautilus (view > show hidden files) then copy the hidden folders of your choice AKA application you will still use.

Comment: Won't the settings be messed up?

Answer (score 0):

Copy/Replace the entire usr/previous user/home with your new /usr/current user/home

Go to user a/c and delete the old one with all files