# Infinite loop of logins in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: server, nvidia, login

When I go to the `home` user and enter my password, I see a black screen, then flashes and it back to the login screen and asks me to reinsert my password in an infinite loop of logins.

I entered in TTY pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and login from there without problems. But when I try to enter with `startx` or `xinit` I get a `server error (1)`

We try to reconfigure xinit, try and purge, remove, clean, re-install xinit but I still have the receipt problem.

**I can only enter in the guest session, in my personal session passes this problem**

I have Ubuntu 12.10 and unity for default and my graphic card is a GeForce 6200 (not problem with card, windows not have problem)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/126634/unable-to-sign-into-11-10-user

Comment: Is not the problem...

Comment: Ubuntu says that your password is wrong?

Comment: Could you use the guest account, and tell me if you have a file named ".Xauthority" on your user home folder?

Comment: PS: If you can't see hidden files (.dotFile) use Ctrl+H to show them.

Comment: Yes, i have a .Xauthority

Comment: I fix it ! I rename the .Xauthority.. reboot and solve  it!

THank you so much !!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a Login Loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)