# Ubuntu not booting right. No taskbar. No unity. No left bar. No programs. Error windows don't have a title bar

Tags: unity, gnome, shortcut-keys, compiz

I keep ubuntu up-to-date. I turned on my computer today and It was slow to boot, only reponding after I moved my mouse a bit. Then it got to the screen with an error message but the error message didn't have a title bar/header. There was no taskbar. I couldn't pull up the left bar or open unity from the super key. I couldn't open the terminal from ctrl-alt-t. The only thing I could do was do ctrl-alt-delete. The task manager pulled up in the top left of the screen without a title bar. My CPU usage was erratic and wildly fluctuating. Ram was steady. I noticed a bump in my network usage. What should I do?

Comment: What was the error message?

Comment: It was just a regular error window that didn't give any information. Ubuntu has experienced an error. [cancel] [report]

Comment: Do you use NVidia or ATI or <insert special video card here> ?

Comment: AMD ATI E2 VISION

Comment: Did you install the drivers for it before this happened?

Comment: No, I was using the proprietary driver for a while and it was working fine. Even when I used the beta. I reinstalled when 14.04 was released and continued to use the proprietary driver without a problem.

Comment: Does Alt+F2 do anything? Can it open a window?

Comment: Alt-F4, after repeated pressing closes the the error windows after I select them by clicking on them. Haven't tried Alt-F2 yet. Currently I'm using windows from my dual boot to post this.

Comment: Try alt+f2 and then compiz --replace

Comment: Tried Alt-F2. No response. When I was booting a message came up on the black screen something about kernel. Too fast to catch the whole message.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Compiz (and possibly lightdm) aren't starting properly.

Drop to a TTY and do 'sudo service compiz start' or try 'sudo service lightdm restart'

Comment: How? I don't know much about TTY. Okay. found it. http://askubuntu.com/questions/66195/what-is-a-tty-and-how-do-i-access-a-tty

Comment: You can access a TTY by holding ctrl+alt and hitting any of the F1-F6 keys.  You will be presented with a full screen terminal (more or less).  

To get back to your desktop just hold CTRL+ALT and hit F7.

Comment: beat me to it. wait, did you get that from my alt+f2 compiz comment???

Comment: Tried Ctrl-Alt-F1. it said that compiz was an unrecognized service and "sudo service lightdm restart" brought me back to my desktop nothing got fixed.

Comment: Compiz is finnicky, try something like
    'compiz --replace'
or
    'DISPLAY=:0 compiz --replace'
From TTY1

Comment: Tried 'compiz --replace'. Didn't work. from TTY1

Comment: tried 'DISPLAY=:0 compiz --replace' on TTY1 didn't work. It gave me

Comment: It gave me compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core. compiz (core) - Info: starting plugin: core. compiz (core): Info: Loading plugin: ccp. compiz (core): Info: starting plugin: ccp. compizconfig - Info Backend: ini. compizconfig - info: Integration: true. compizconfig - Info: profile: default. then it stops. desktop is the same as ever. No improvement.

Comment: I reinstalled ubuntu.