# No GUI and Long on screen in ubuntu 14.04 after removing GTK

Tags: 14.04, login, gtk, gtk3

I removed the `gtk+2` and `gtk+3` by the command `apt-get remove` command.
But after that, I could not log on to my system, there is no Log in screen and other GUI icons. But the PC is working, I could access the files in it through the network (using putty).

How can I bring back the GUI properties and the log in screen...
At present I can't directly access my PC (only a black screen).
Please help me, it's very urgent for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you uninstalled only `gtk+`, command line should still work.

1. Turn on the PC.
2. After Ubuntu boots press `ctrl+alt+f2` to switch to command line mode.
3. Login. First it asks your username, then password. There will be *no* indication that you are typing password. Just press `Enter` after you've finished. Language settings may be different from usual, try them when asked for username.
4. Type `sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-0 libgtk2.0-0`
5. After computer finished downloading press `ctrl+alt+f7`
6. Profit?

See [What is a tty, and how do I access a tty?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66195/what-is-a-tty-and-how-do-i-access-a-tty) for reference.

Comment: If that does not help, you can reinstall full Ubuntu suite by running `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: He may have to restart his computer. By the way the question is really _I removed my GUI Librarys why is my GUI not working?_