# can i load terminal before booting ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: boot, command-line

When I download updates for my nvidia geforce 8800gt, the screen turns black and the cursor is blinking at the top left corner. I am forced to reinstall ubuntu. Is it possible to run terminal before I boot ubuntu?

Comment: you can try to hit CTRL+ALT+F2 to access a terminal. See also [this question about TTY](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66195/what-is-a-tty-and-how-do-i-access-a-tty)

Answer (score 0):

There is something known as root recovery shell. You can access it through grub boot menu -> Advanced options for Ubuntu -> select one that says `(recovery mode)`. You will have several options there, choose root shell. The filesystem in root shell is mounted read-only, so you will need to remount it with read write permissions with `mount / -o remount,rw`

Another small hack is to press e on the boot menu and add `init=/bin/bash` line , but I wouldn't recomment it.

Comment: Thank you for the information, but it does not help. I try to remove the drivers but the Terminal says there are not installed. The blinking is still there, usually it turns orange. Also, if I remove the graphic card, Ubuntu loads normally.