# (Windows10) Ubuntu bash multitasking. is it possbile

Tags: bash, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

(I'm newbie , sorry for possibnly silly questions)

I heard bash has a capability of multitasking. I mean an ability to run a few terminals/console applications and switch between these (Ctrl+Alt+Fx??) .

is it possible in ubuntu subsystem in Windows 10

Comment: Those are TTYs, and I don't think are part of WSL http://askubuntu.com/questions/66195/what-is-a-tty-and-how-do-i-access-a-tty

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run apps in the background on Bash on Windows (see [this useful guide](https://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/unix-linux-job-control-command-examples-for-bash-ksh-shell/)).

### Update 2018-02-06

Removed previous caveat since we recently introduced the ability for WSL to keep your daemons/background-services running even if you close all your Linux consoles: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/12/04/background-task-support-in-wsl/

Also, yes, WSL supports backgrounding tasks, running multiple sessions in different panes of a single Console via tmux/screen, or multiple Windows Console instances operating the same distro instance.