# new to ubuntu need command help?

Tags: command-line, vim

ok I have installed Ubuntu server on a Asus z10pe w8 ws mb with two xeon e5 2683 v3, with a older geforce gtx 670, lots of ram and hd space, trying to make home server at first it only loaded to grub, dos 5 like environment with different commands, went through a few posts to see if i can install the desktop,i found a few commands, so I installed the gdu, got the desktop up and running, but have no apts on it, have settings and help, no terminal, no vim but have  vim icon, can open dvd, from install but have not been able to execute any files, any input on where to go from here?

[image: screen1]

Comment: This is because you installed the server edition with no GUI. The when you added the desktop, you only added the basic functionality of the desktop. The best solution for you IMO, install the desktop version, it still has the features of the server but also a Desktop. https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop

Answer (score 4):

No need to reinstall Ubuntu. You can install Unity **and** the other desktop related packages by installing ubuntu-desktop with the packages it suggests.

1) [Go to TTY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66195/what-is-a-tty-and-how-do-i-access-a-tty) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>)

2) Install desktop: `sudo apt-get --install-suggests install ubuntu-desktop`

3) Reboot: `reboot`