# Is the terminal named "?" the grandmother of all processes?

Tags: boot, command-line, init

When I invoke the `gnome-control-center` from the search bar

[image: searching for "gnome-control" in the Applications menu]

The true command which the os runs can be found in `ps`:

```
me@alpha:~$ ps -ef | grep gnome-control-center 
me   13952  7293  0 12:20 tty2     00:00:00 gnome-control-center
me   15523  7835  0 12:27 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto gnome-control-center
```

It indicates that the operating system opens a terminal `tty2`, inputs command `gnome-control-center`, and presses Enter.

When it comes to the init or systemd process

```
me@alpha:~$ ps -ef | head -5
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 10:34 ?        00:00:05 /sbin/init splash
root         2     0  0 10:34 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
root         3     2  0 10:34 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_gp]
root         4     2  0 10:34 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_par_gp]
```

With reference to the PID 1, its command is `/sbin/init splash`.

From where is it input, `/sbin/init splash`, and press Enter?

The tty is `?` which stands for a daemon process.

Is it right if I understand that daemon processes are invoked from a terminal whose name is `?` and this terminal is the grandmother of all processes?

#### Note:

Thanks for Sergiy's tutorial about Kernel.

I got the idea intuitively from a picture from a book called "Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment".

The system call `fork` is to spawn a new process which could be called from shell or from applications.

[image: diagram from book]

Comment: Note that tty2 is already open - that's the TTY that the GUI runs on (in 18.04). For more details see [What is a tty, and how do I access a tty?](https://askubuntu.com/q/66195/301745) Also the system doesn't press Enter to execute a command, but I'm not sure how it actually works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `?` symbol indicates that there is no `tty` associated with the process. In other words, there is no real or virtual device where that process can write information. However, the `/sbin/init` process is in fact "grandmother" of all processes on the system, directly or indirectly. Where does it come from ? The Linux kernel starts it. The kernel can be called "grand-grandmother" of all processes.  The steps are described in  [Linux kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.17/admin-guide/initrd.html):

> Operation
>
> When using initrd, the system typically boots as follows:
>
> 1. the boot loader loads the kernel and the initial RAM disk
> 2. the kernel converts initrd into a “normal” RAM disk and frees the memory used by initrd
> 3. if the root device is not /dev/ram0, the old (deprecated) change_root procedure is followed. see the “Obsolete root change
>      mechanism” section below.
> 4. root device is mounted. if it is /dev/ram0, the initrd image is then mounted as root
> 5. /sbin/init is executed (this can be any valid executable, including shell scripts; it is run with uid 0 and can do basically everything
>      init can do).
> 6. init mounts the “real” root file system
> 7. init places the root file system at the root directory using the pivot_root system call
> 8. init execs the /sbin/init on the new root filesystem, performing the usual boot sequence
> 9. the initrd file system is removed

Note also that `?` indicates it is a daemon. To quote [daemon(7) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/daemon.7.html):

> A daemon is a service process that runs in the background and
>          supervises the system or provides functionality to other processes.

Comment: Thank you and get the idea of kernel. they are of kernel's system call 'fork'

Comment: @Alice Yes, exactly. All processes on Linux are result of `fork()` syscall