# After 19.10 upgrade I have an extra frozen cursor

Tags: upgrade, cursor, 19.10

I recently upgraded from 19.04 to 19.10.  Ever since, there has been an extra (large) cursor in the lower right of my screen.  It is frozen and does not move.  It returns on the lockscreen, sleep and restore, and also persists unmoved when I change workspaces or bring up the dash.

Interestingly, while here is a clear demonstration this cursor exists from an external (phone) picture:

[image]

When I use the screen shot utility, even with "include cursor" selected, I cannot capture the phantom cursor, just the true cursor.

[image]

How can I make this frozen phantom cursor disappear?

Comment: Does the cursor change when you change the background?  I'm wondering if this is some kind of trick image.  Also, is this on the actual machine or through a remote session?  I know this is clutching at straws but the thing that's really odd is that they're different sizes.  Can you also include the contents of `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and/or `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/*`?

Comment: Also, I tested this and this is *not* the normal behaviour of UA's "Mouse Keys".

Comment: Is there any sort of magnifier accessibility program running in the background?

Comment: @tu-ReinstateMonica-dorduh, I appear to have neither of those files?```$ cat /etc/X11/x
xinit/ xkb/   xsm/   
```

Comment: @QuickishFM, not intentionally, and I am not aware of one.  Is that Orca to look for in task manager?

Comment: What's the output of `xinput list`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change the interface at logging screen? Does the cursor still appear whatever interface you select ?

[image]

(I don't have Ubuntu 19 but 18.04 LTS but I guess changing interface should work the same (?))

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, though not related to upgrading, so this may be of help to others with a similar bug on 18.04. I had been trying to add additional monitor displays which caused an extra (frozen) cursor to appear.

I tried switching to a different [TTY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66195/what-is-a-tty-and-how-do-i-access-a-tty)  (via `crtl alt F7`) and then back to desktop (`crtl alt F1`). On the login screen, the second cursor was gone, so I logged in. When I pressed enter, my current cursor became frozen and a second cursor appeared which I had control over.

There must be some GNOME Ubuntu magic happening behind the scenes with this bug, and this isn't a complete solution, but at least I could "move" the second cursor (into a corner) before logging in to desktop.