# How do I get Ubuntu 18.04.3 GUI back from tty?

Tags: 18.04, gui, tty

I have tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and other possible ways, but still cannot get my GUI back from tty.

Comment: `CTRL` + `ALT` + `F1` doesn't work?

Comment: You have tagged `python`, have you made changes to your python?  What do you get with `python -V; python3 -V`  (you should get two lines of output).  Are you talking about Ubuntu Server? or Ubuntu Desktop?

Comment: CTRL + ALT + F1 doesn't work. This problem is started after I installed python 3.6.9 on my Ubuntu 18.04.3 desktop. After I installed 18.04.3, my terminal stop working so I move to tty. Now, I am stuck on tty and can't return back to Ubuntu GUI.

Comment: @Nmath CTRL + ALT + F1 doesn't work.

Comment: The problem you have doesn't seem to be the one you've asked about. I recommend making a significant edit to your question (including the title) to explain your actual problem in detail.  The more effort you put into providing helpful details, the better chance for someone to understand the issue and offer a solution.

Comment: @DDN Did u check this ->> https://askubuntu.com/questions/66195/what-is-a-tty-and-how-do-i-access-a-tty

You just press `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F2` then GUI will come back to you.

Comment: @heechanLee Yes, I have done all possible ways to get back my Ubuntu GUI. But, I failed.

Comment: All possible ways?  (*If you tried all possible ways it's re-install time*..) Your fix to get help from us though is what @Nmath has already suggested, your question still makes no mention of the `python3` changes (only the tag that led to my question), the results of the question I asked etc... Extra detail should be added to your question (you can edit your own questions) and not added via comment.  Currently we're waiting for your responses  (it should also include details of the python3 changes you made since they seem very critical!)

Answer (score 0):

Simply reboot with `reboot` in the console if you can't get your GUI from Fxxx.

Comment: after I reboot, it directly goes to tty again not Ubuntu GUI

Comment: oh !  try running a: "startx"   at any risk, you would not remove "some" package in addition to installing your version of python? (without looking too much at or understanding the warnings?)

Comment: witch version ubuntu ? xubunu, lubuntu or ubuntu classic ? if "startx" do nothing try a: "sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop"  (or xubunu-desktop/lubuntu-desktop depending on your initial version)

Comment: Thanks a lot. My problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question and your situation, but you might have managed to remove the GUI(which I did a while ago). If this is the issue, I would try to run the command `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` to install the default GUI in ubuntu. If the package installs, reboot with `reboot` and you should be good to go.