# Linux Ubuntu 20.04 not working after adding second user

Tags: 20.04, users, user-management

I added a new user to my Dell laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 version installed on it.
After I added the new user and restarted my computer it will not show any icons or images at all.
I can open some programs but everything else is ether blank or i can't open it.

Can any one help me?

Comment: Yes. I've tried rebooting it a few times, and it still does the same thing.

Comment: Review your /var/log/syslog for error messages during the most recent boot

Comment: I can't. It will not let me view it.

Comment: Look up [how use a TTY terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66195/what-is-a-tty-and-how-do-i-access-a-tty) instead of a desktop window  (GUI) terminal.