# Sometimes I get a black screen

Tags: 20.04, gdm

On Ubuntu 20.04 sometimes when I get out of sleep I have just a black screen. I might get it also just when I get out of the lockout. The login page does not appear I just have a black screen.

I use 2 screens, the first one is a laptop screen reversed and an external monitor which is the primary one.

So I think that it's a GDM issue. Where to check what bugs? Is there any log file?

Comment: Are you able to access a TTY terminal or is that black as well? Here is a previously asked answer that explains what TTY is if you aren't sure: https://askubuntu.com/questions/66195/what-is-a-tty-and-how-do-i-access-a-tty

Comment: Not at all the time, but I did! Once on the TTY terminal I just did a reboot finally.

Comment: Do you have noveau in use? (Nvidia driver)? That only applies if you have a nvidia card in your system.

Comment: I have the Nvidia proprietary driver installed with flatpack `nvidia-470-57-02    org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-470-57-02    1.4    user`