# Accidentaly broke Konsole (Kubuntu) after changing the default command

Tags: command-line, bash, kubuntu, kde, konsole

I was testing some features in Konsole (Plasma's terminal) and accidentally set the command when you open it to something that is not bash and now it just flashes when I open.

The default command to open Konsole was `/bin/bash` and I changed to `neofetch && /bin/bash` but I typed something wrong and now terminal don't open bash and just flashes when opened.

I was wondering if there is some way to reset or reinstall it, but I didn't find anything useful on google.

Comment: Have you tried to install nother console from MUON package manager or Discovery ?

Comment: you can also perfom a `sudo apt-get install -reinstall konsole` when you can.

Comment: Without telling us what exactly you did, it will be hard to tell you how to reverse it.  You should edit your question and include exact details. Include all steps and commands.

Comment: If you only messed up Konsole, you can [just use a TTY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66195/what-is-a-tty-and-how-do-i-access-a-tty) to reinstall console (I would do `sudo apt update && sudo apt purge konsole && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt install konsole` personally, just to get rid of any config files). Or, just install a different terminal emulator. If you messed with your `.bashrc` instead of the terminal, you can boot to a live CD, and use the live CD to fix your `.bashrc` file.

Comment: I doubt resinstalling the package will help - the profile settings are likely stored on a per-user basis, no? You may need to find and delete the bad profile (likely in `~/.local/konsole/`)

Comment: @steeldriver Oh, I deleted the folder and all of my profiles disappeared, now Konsole is working fine. Thanks!