# My new install of Ubuntu loads for about 5 to 10 seconds before going to a black screen. Where do I start?

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 to dual boot alongside windows 11. I actually ran the OS on the flash drive first with no problems. After install and restart it will show the desktop for about 5 to 10 seconds before going to a black screen showing only the cursor. Then after a couple more seconds the cursor goes away as well. This is my first Linux experience and I don't know where to start.

Comment: When it goes to just the cursor, can you access a TTY? Directions for that are here - https://askubuntu.com/a/66198/1438484 - it isn't too hard to do, though