# Command who question

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is tty7 in the commandline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27339/what-is-tty7-in-the-commandline)

Why when I type the command `who` does it show

```
my_username tty7
my_username pts/0
```

Shouldn't it just show one?  Why am I logged in twice? And what is the difference between `tty7` and `pts/0`?

Comment: Searched for tty on the site yet? One here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/66195/what-is-a-tty-and-how-do-i-access-a-tty

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two is actually the answer to both questions posed. See https://askubuntu.com/a/27444/23727