# How to reinstall Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: command-line

The system has become too slow and Terminal tool does not work.

I deleted Ubuntu Software Center.

How do I download it again?

Comment: Please try to make questions more readable and give more informations what you did and what you want to achive.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: my version is16.4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Luckily, the desktop environment runs on top of another terminal, called a [TTY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27339/what-is-tty7-in-the-commandline). A TTY is a basic terminal found on the system, which the desktop environment runs on top of. To access TTY1, use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

1. A text-based login screen should appear. Login with your regular username and password. The password will not appear on-screen.
2. Use apt-get to re-install the terminal:

   1. First call `sudo apt-get update` to make sure you will install the latest version.
   2. Then `sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal` to actually install the missing terminal.
   3. The software center can then be installed with `sudo apt-get install software-center`.
3. Sign out with `logout`. You can return to the regular desktop environment with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

If want more information installing software with the command line, see

- [What does "sudo apt-get update" do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222348/what-does-sudo-apt-get-update-do) and
- [what does "sudo apt-get install aptitude" do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/311130/what-does-sudo-apt-get-install-aptitude-do)

Comment: In Ubuntu 18 `software-center` has been replaced with `gnome-software`, so use `sudo apt install gnome-software` for step 2.3 instead. See here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036506/how-do-i-install-software-center-on-ubuntu-18-04/1036694#1036694.

Comment: @GabrielStaples, your solution is the only one that worked for me. It seems 'gnome-software' sessions are not handled properly by the system (closing, reopening, etc).

Comment: Error handling could also be improved on the App. It easily breaks whenever an error occurs with any installed application.

Answer (score 3):

**To install Ubuntu Software Center - please follow these 3 steps**

To fetch the latest package installations:

```
sudo apt update
```

To install all current updates:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

To install the software-center again:

```
sudo apt install software-center
```

Comment: @michal rejected your proposal to edit: apt will work for update, upgrade and install. No need to use apt-get instead.

Comment: @MadMike The editor will not be informed, when you reject and edit, if you wish, you can choose `causes harm` and add a custom reason, to let them know but unless it is there post or they comment, they will not get the notification. Apt will work but only on 16.04.

Comment: @MarkKirby thanks for the hint. As for apt: I have just upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 this weekend and I have used apt on 14.04 for some time successfully.

Comment: @MadMike You can but you must install `apt` package first (unless it was added in an update and I don't know), soon `apt` will completely replace `apt-get`, it is not a big deal, older version users will be prompted to install `apt` if it is missing