# How do I install software center on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: package-management, video

I can't launch the Software & Updates center in Bionic Beaver. No video application will open. I tried to install the software center manually and got the following output:

```
neil@neil-ThinkPad-T420:~$ sudo apt-get install software-center
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package software-center is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate
```

I'm not a technical adept and can barely follow simple terminal instructions. I need help.

Comment: Why not using the tools provided with Ubuntu 18.04 ? Or if you prefer, synaptic is very good too (sudo apt-get install synaptic).

Comment: @PhilippeGaucher What tool provided with Ubuntu 18.04 replaced Software Center?

Comment: @AdamBliss I use synaptic, there is something called gnome-software (I use gnome). Probably a lot of other possibilities.

Answer (score 23):

software-center has been replaced with gnome-software. So just type in a terminal

```
sudo apt install gnome-software
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked!

Answer (score 5):

as quality of packages in Ubuntu is going down the drain, Synaptic Package Manager is a decent replacement to Ubuntu Software Center, and is much better (far less buggy) than Gnome Software.

you can install it with:

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get *Software & Updates* - it is located in [`software-properties-gtk`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/software-properties-gtk/filelist) package.

You can install it with:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-gtk
```