# I accidentally removed alsa-utils

Tags: gnome, alsa

accidentally I removed alsa-utils. After that i reinstalled it but I have a feeling that something is missing. For sure Ubuntu Software Center was removed and right now i can't install it.

I installed GNOME Software, but I don't have a luck installing Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reinstall Ubuntu Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779325/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-software-center) If you’ve tried these tips, please [edit] your question and post your results. Apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) to commands and their output.

Comment: Hey I did it  with the TTY. Thanks for this post. I didn't see it !