# Ubuntu Software App

Tags: software-center

My Ubuntu Software App doesn't do anything. Search won't display anything just cursor hovering endlessly. Clicking any of the categories in explore tab just shows blank buttons. Clicking on any of the installed app in "Installed Tab" would forever be "Loading application details...". Clicking GREEN Update All button in "Updates Tab" would pop a message "Unable to install updates: snap has no updates available.
Any idea what's wrong?
I'm using ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and new to Ubuntu. I noticed this app is pretty clumsy since the beginning and gradually got to a point where it doesn't do anything.

Comment: try to reinstall it https://askubuntu.com/questions/779325/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-software-center

Comment: Thanks. Reinstalling has fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would try with :

```
sudo snap remove --purge snap-store
sudo snap refresh
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt autoremove --purge
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoclean
sudo snap install snap-store
```

Comment: Thanks. Reinstalling has fix the issue.

Comment: @ME_Clueless don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ and turn it green ✅. This will indicate the problem is solved and help others.